# Avocado tree - brown leaves black underside

Tags: plant-health, transplanting, avocado

We planted an avocado tree and within a week or so the leaves started browning and there were black dots on the underside. I'm wondering if the tree is experiencing transplant shock, but I feel like this is more than that. Does anyone know what is happening or how to possible fix it? The tree is planted in Southern California.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like this tree has been dry and hot for a while, Have you been watering it regularly?

Comment: I water it about every other day. Maybe I'm not giving it enough water or the water isn't reaching the roots.